# Delete a line does not start with # and match a pattern

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I am trying to delete the line which does not start with # and match the pattern localhost from the file

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost           <---- line I want to delete
127.0.0.2       abcabc
```

I have tried the following scripts, but doesn't work.

```
sed -i "/^[^#](.*)localhost$/d" /etc/hosts

sed -i "/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/d" /etc/hosts
```

How can i delete the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default sed takes `()` as a literal characters , not as a capturing groups.

```
sed -i "/^[^#].*localhost$/d" /etc/hosts
```

OR

```
sed -i "/^[^#].* \+localhost.*$/d" /etc/hosts
```

There may be some chances of spaces would present just after to the string `localhost`, so i added `.*` next to the string `localhost` in the above command.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.2       abcabc
$ sed "/^[^#].*localhost$/d" file
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.2       abcabc
```

Comment: or `sed "/^[^#].*[[:space:]]\+localhost$/d" file`

Answer (score 0):

```
"/^[^#]*localhost$/d"
```

You can simply use this as argument to `sed` to delete the required line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/localhost/ && !/#/ {next} 1'
```

Result

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.2       abcabc
```

Comment: You should use `!/^#/` to tell that comment is in start of line.  Other than that `awk` is simple and understandable:  Skip all line with `localhost` and not containing `#`